# Ошибка при выводе значения из MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

alert выводит только значения, состоящие из цифр. Если "подмешиваю" буквы - появляется ошибка Uncaught ReferenceError: yyyyyyyy is not defined

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','bla','bla','bla');
$sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT data, content FROM sinc");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
echo "<script>alert (".$result['data'].")</script>";
}
```

?>

Comment: вы скрипт, выполняющийся в браузере видите? А как должны выглядеть строки в js помните?

Comment: напишу более очевидный комментарий: быть может не хватает кавычек? оО

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<script>alert('".$result['data']."')</script>";
```

Ист.:

1. *Комментарий:* №1, *автор:* [vp_arth](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176064/vp-arth);
2. *Комментарий:* №2, *автор:* teran, *изд.:* StackOverflow, 2017.